# What is 'base' attribute in xml?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Hey I was just going through some article on XML, I came across the following snippet of code

```
<xs:element name="shirtSize">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:enumeration value="36"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="40"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I was wondering what **base** keyword means in the line

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:int">
```

Can anyone please explain me what it means??
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base` is not, strictly speaking, a keyword. It is part of [XML Schema (XSD)](http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema) "language", letting you create simple types by restricting other simple types, including [built-in numeric types](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_numeric.asp).

In your case, the integer value is restricted to two values - 36 and 40.

Answer (score 0):

On **base** attribute, you can specify

1. which data type, you want to use such as `xs:int`, `xs:string`, `xs:long` and soon
2. User Defined type can be set
3. You can do restriction with the following:

   • length 
      • minLength  
      • maxLength  
      • pattern   
      • enumeration   
      • whiteSpace and some more too based on type

Comment: -1: `base` isn't the data type itself, it is the XSD attribute with which you specify the base data type for the type being define. (Small difference, but to use XSD that difference is everything.)

Comment: @Richard: I mean, it is used to specify which datatype to be used for the element

Answer (score 0):

This element declaration specifies that the type of the element is an anonymous type formed as a restriction of the built-in type xs:int, the restriction being that the only allowed values are 36 and 40. The attribute name "base" is used in xs:restriction to name the type that is being restricted.